# Error when creating sites from custom site template

Tags: site-template

I've created a site template based on a Team Site by going into Site Settings and choosing Save site as template. However, when I try to create a new site based on this site template I get the following error:

> ERROR "Workflows" cannot be used as a sitename. site names cannot
>   contian certain reserved words and cannot begin with an underscore.
>   Please enter a different name. Correlation ID:
>   {31690ae6-39d9-4c6a-b721-fd737c26fc55}

I'm not entering "workflows" as the site name so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. and the site doesn't have any workflows.

I checked the logs and found the following:

> Failed to activate site-scoped features for template 'STS#0' in site
>   'myserver/sitecollection/testing'.    71ef0dc4-7ecb-454a-b794-5a5da16a46e6
>   Failed to activate web features when provisioning site at url
>   "myserver/sitecollection/testing" with site definition
>   "STS#0".  71ef0dc4-7ecb-454a-b794-5a5da16a46e6 Failed to apply template
>   "STS#0" to web at URL
>   "myserver/sitecollection/testing".    71ef0dc4-7ecb-454a-b794-5a5da16a46e6
>   Failed to apply template "STS#0" to web at URL
>   "myserver/sitecollection/testing", error "Workflows" cannot be used as
>   a site name. Site names cannot contain certain reserved words and
>   cannot begin with an underscore. Please enter a different name.
>   0x3321b400    71ef0dc4-7ecb-454a-b794-5a5da16a46e6
>   0x8107058a"Workflows"
>   cannot be used as a site name. Site names cannot contain certain
>   reserved words and cannot begin with an underscore. Please enter a
>   different name.   71ef0dc4-7ecb-454a-b794-5a5da16a46e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link 
http://www.brainlitter.com/2012/12/23/sharepoint-sites-and-reserved-words-may-not-be-what-they-appear-to-be/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that article help me out. I did have a managed path called workflows in my Web Application. Removing the managed path did the trick.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. [mod]

Comment: He didn't use "workflows" as the site name so it is not the right answer I believe?